# Visual Studio load test, changing identity of remote agent

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

With a visual studio load test project, I execute a simple call on a web service using a distributed pattern (the calls are made from a group of 4 remote agents).

The calls to the web service are executed with a user account corresponding to the name of the agent machine (e.g. domain\AGENT1$). I would like to influence the credentials of this call, so that a different user is transmitted in the http context, is this possible? I have played with the .testsettings file but to no avail.

The load test is composed of a single web test which calls a GET REST API method of the style: http://myserver/Something/1234. There is therefore no coded component and the credentials it seems are simply taken from the process executing the call, that is the test agent.

Comment: Using different credentials is normally possible but there are several schemes for passing the credentials. How do you put the `domain\AGENT1$` value into the http context? Please [edit] the question to show what the test does now.

Comment: I added some more information about the load test itself. I do not explicitly set the value in the http context. I discovered that I could influence the credentials by configuring the agent service to run with a different user account but this is not ideal as it then affects all applications which are testing using the agent.

Comment: I think the answer is as simple as (1) use the "Set credentials" command (access via the padlock icon) of the web test editor and (2) data drive the tests with username and password.

Comment: That worked perfectly, just what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: In fact in the case where I have a web test which contains a web plugin this doesn't seem to work correctly. The web test plugin code (which formulates a POST of a file) is still executed using the agent account. However I also see a request which does not originate from the test plugin but which uses the correct account which I set in the "set credentials" dialog. The fact that is does no pass by the web plugin code means the POST is completely incorrect and therefore in both cases the request will fail.

Comment: I do not really understand your last comment. Please [edit] the question to clearly describe the problem you are seeing. If you are building a request in a plugin then you also need to add the required credentials to that request. Please add a [mcve] showing the plugin how it is used.